# AWS boto3 unable to put tags after creating an AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I'm trying to put tags after creating AMI from an instance using boto3 and getting an error:

> botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
>   Unknown parameter in input: "TagSpecifications", must be one of:
>   BlockDeviceMappings, Description, DryRun, InstanceId, Name, NoReboot

Here is my code, can you please check what I'm doing wrong?

It works for snapshot but failing for image.

```
import xlrd
import boto3
import datetime

client = boto3.client('ec2')


# Give the location of the file
loc = ("/Users/user1/Documents/aws-python/aws-tag-test (1).xlsx")

# To open Workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# For row 0 and column 0
#print (sheet.cell_value(0, 0))

nowtime = datetime.datetime.now()
nowdate = (nowtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M"))
print (nowdate)

#print (nowtime)

server_ids = []
instancename =[]
for i in range (1,sheet.nrows):
    server_ids.append(sheet.cell_value(i,1))
    instancename.append(sheet.cell_value(i,0))


    #print (sheet.cell_value(i,1))
# excel closed

for i in range (len(server_ids)):
    print(server_ids[i], instancename[i])
    response = client.create_image(
        Description     = 'ami ' + instancename[i] + ' ' + str(nowdate),
        InstanceId      = server_ids[i],
        Name            = 'ami ' + instancename[i] + ' ' + str(nowdate),
        NoReboot        = True,
        DryRun=False,
        TagSpecifications=[
            {
                'ResourceType': 'image',
                'Tags': [
                    {
                        'Key': 'Name',
                        'Value': 'ami-' + instancename[i] + '-' + str(nowdate)
                    },
                    {
                        'Key': 'date',
                        'Value': datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
)
#)


print(response)
```

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: CreateImage does not have a "TagSpecifications" request parameter. Refer to the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateImage.html. You need to use create-tags after you have the AMI resource ID and tag it that way.

Comment: Just to be really clear, you can see there is no `TagSpecifications` parameter in [create_image](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_image). You will then need to call [create_tags](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags).

Comment: There is TagSpecifications parameter in create image, its clearly shown in docs. @dmulter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is now available. Not sure when, but it was definitely added sometime after the original comments.